# Get mobile phone's unique ID from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cross-browser, identification

I have used the great Google, and have found many a post, but all were from the yester-years.

I'm trying to uniquely identify a mobile phone when it visits my webpage. Everything I've found so far says it can't be done, but these are all old posts so maybe something has come along in the past years which makes it possible.

I realize I can simply create a unique code myself and store it in a cookie, but of course these cookies do not work cross browser. And a mobile phone uses a different browser when a page is visited from, for instance, Facebook, or WeChat, or what not.

The reason I want to identify the mobile phone is because I want a user's settings to persist whenever he visit's my website. And it shouldn't matter if he visits my website through the built-in browser, or through one of the earlier mentioned other methods.

Can this be done at all? Or is it still not possible? I don't want the user having to install anything extra.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can all be done with user-accounts. You can't have cross-browser/cross-client persistent data

Comment: Yes, I understand that too. But I also don't want to force a user to create an account right away. Preferably, I want a user account to be optional which gives the user the added ability to use his account on multiple devices (and protect him from loosing his settings whenever his cookies are cleared for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Look into device and browser fingerprinting. They use things like installed fonts, GPU type, and other innocuous things, that when tied together and hashed give you a reasonable guess about whether you've seen the user before.

I here [this](https://www.augur.io/) possibly paid solution works well.